# Is it possible to force `git checkout` to treat the ref as a commit hash?

Tags: git

This is a somewhat academic / esoteric question, because I know it's not a good idea to name a branch after a commit hash. However, I'm curious.

It seems that if I name a branch after a hash `X`, and then do `git checkout X`, git will prefer the branch name. Fortunately, it will warn about it.

```
$ git checkout f878084412c04542e297cb5c52b0fb6f6a2b2870
warning: refname 'f878084412c04542e297cb5c52b0fb6f6a2b2870' is ambiguous.
Git normally never creates a ref that ends with 40 hex characters
because it will be ignored when you just specify 40-hex. These refs
may be created by mistake. For example,

  git switch -c $br $(git rev-parse ...)

where "$br" is somehow empty and a 40-hex ref is created. Please
examine these refs and maybe delete them. Turn this message off by
running "git config advice.objectNameWarning false"
Switched to branch 'f878084412c04542e297cb5c52b0fb6f6a2b2870'
```

Is it possible to force `git checkout <arg>` to treat the `<arg>` as a commit hash instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no: if the name exactly matches some `refs/heads/*` name, `git checkout` will treat it as that branch name.

There's a simple workaround: drop the last digit.  You now have an "ambiguous" 39-character-long hash ID.  Suppose $H expands to these 39 characters: the possible hash IDs are then `${H}0`, `${H}1`, ..., `${H}f`, for a total of 16 possible hash IDs.  It's extremely unlikely that there is more than one match, and Git will then treat the shortened hash ID as a hash ID, rather than as the branch name.

(There's a second simple workaround, which is to rename the branch name, of course. :-) )

Comment: A third workaround, as the warning said, "delete them" :->